# How to notify a child element that a job has finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a child element that displays a list of orders that it gets passed from the parent. I want to place a "Refresh" button inside the child which, once pressed, calls a function inside the parent to refresh the orders.

When the refresh button is clicked, its text goes to "loading..." by using a local state hook. The problem is I am not sure how to change the hook's state back to "not loading" after the newly refreshed order list arrives from the parent.

Here is my code (also at CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wilbur-tbf7l?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const OrderDisplay = ({ orders, refreshOrders }) => {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const handleRefreshBtn = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    refreshOrders();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleRefreshBtn}>
        {refreshing ? <span>loading...</span> : <span>Refresh Orders</span>}
      </button>

      {orders.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          Name: {item.name} | Total: ${item.total}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState(null);
  const initialMount = React.useRef(true);

  const getOrders = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOrders([
        { name: "Order 1", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 },
        { name: "Order 2", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 }
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  };

  if (initialMount.current) {
    initialMount.current = false;
    getOrders();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
      {orders ? (
        <OrderDisplay orders={orders} refreshOrders={getOrders} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

After clicking the "Refresh Orders" button, you will notice that the orders get successfully refreshed, but the button stays at "loading...". How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as the order changes you can set `setRefreshing` to false,like below:

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const OrderDisplay = ({ orders, refreshOrders }) => {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const handleRefreshBtn = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    refreshOrders();
  };
useEffect(()=>{
  if(orders.length)
  {
    setRefreshing(false)
  }

},[orders]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleRefreshBtn}>
        {refreshing ? <span>loading...</span> : <span>Refresh Orders</span>}
      </button>

      {orders.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          Name: {item.name} | Total: ${item.total}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState(null);
  const initialMount = React.useRef(true);

  const getOrders = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOrders([
        { name: "Order 1", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 },
        { name: "Order 2", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 }
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  };

  if (initialMount.current) {
    initialMount.current = false;
    getOrders();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
      {orders ? (
        <OrderDisplay orders={orders} refreshOrders={getOrders} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this wont work if the orders length becomes zero.in that case you can remove the if condition inside the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Read comments in code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const OrderDisplay = ({ orders, refreshOrders }) => {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const handleRefreshBtn = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    //
    //
    // Here you pass your setRefreshing
    // method to getOrders
    refreshOrders(setRefreshing);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleRefreshBtn}>
        {refreshing ? <span>loading...</span> : <span>Refresh Orders</span>}
      </button>

      {orders.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          Name: {item.name} | Total: ${item.total}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState(null);
  const initialMount = React.useRef(true);

  //
  //
  // Here you defining it
  const getOrders = (setRefreshing) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOrders([
        { name: "Order 1", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 },
        { name: "Order 2", total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 }
      ]);
      //
      //
      // Here you use it
      setRefreshing(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  if (initialMount.current) {
    initialMount.current = false;
    getOrders();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
      {orders ? (
        <OrderDisplay orders={orders} refreshOrders={getOrders} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Haven't considered doing it this way. I'm afraid in my specific implementation, this would require too many changes. I think the `useEffect` solution mostly answers my question. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`App` component should pass whether orders is refreshing or not to `OrderDisplay` one. Because it holds that state. So try this approach:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const OrderDisplay = ({ orders, refreshOrders, isRefreshing }) => {
    const handleRefreshBtn = () => {
        refreshOrders();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleRefreshBtn}>
                {isRefreshing ? (
                    <span>loading...</span>
                ) : (
                    <span>Refresh Orders</span>
                )}
            </button>

            {orders.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    Name: {item.name} | Total: ${item.total}
                    <hr />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState(null);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

    // you do not need it see comment above React.useEffect
    // const initialMount = React.useRef(true);

    const getOrders = () => {
        setRefreshing(true)

        setTimeout(() => {
            setOrders([
                { name: 'Order 1', total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 },
                { name: 'Order 2', total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 },
            ]);

            setRefreshing(false);
        }, 1000);
    };
    // useEffect should be used instead of useRef if you need to fetch data
    // pass an empty array as a useEffect dependencies and it will ensures that
    // useEffect will be called only once after initial render
    React.useEffect(() => {
        getOrders();
    }, []);
    //   if (initialMount.current) {
    //     initialMount.current = false;
    //     getOrders();
    //   }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Orders</h1>
            {orders ? (
                <OrderDisplay orders={orders} refreshOrders={getOrders} isRefreshing={refreshing} />
            ) : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why wouldn't you use `useEffect` on the orders variable inside the child element to detect changes? In other words, why wouldn't you do what @Sakshi suggested?

Comment: @codemonkey if your orders for the first time is { name: 'Order 1', total: 3,
                { name: 'Order 2', total:4}, and second time is also the same(let's say) then for the 2nd time the useEffect wont come into the picture,because useEffect will work only when there is a change in the orders.Hence 2nd time refreshing value wont be set to false.So if you are sure that the orders would change each and every time you click on the refresh button then useEffect approach is good.

Comment: @codemonkey because there might be a case when orders list is refreshed but with no orders in the list.

Comment: @OleksandrSakun for that one can remove the if condition present inside the useEffect

Comment: @Sakshi But that's not true. I just made the order list the same every time it refreshes: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wilbur-tbf7l?file=/src/App.js It still works like a charm. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Sakshi you are right, seems like we can relay on orders list reference in useEffect.

Comment: @codemonkey `useEffect` compare arrays by reference. So if you move orders out of component scope in some variable and use that variable in setTimeout you will see permanent loading after button is clicked